# How to implement specific url for search query like Google using normal webapp running on PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, search

In Gmail or Google search itself,

I believe whenever you do a search, a unique url is generated so that you can always press the back button on the browser without worry.

You can also bookmark the unique url or send it and other people will see the same thing.

I want to implement the same setup for an intranet web app built using PHP and MySQL.

I believe that I need at least the following table:

```
search_results
  id PRIMARY char(36)
  query TEXT
```

After that I have no real clue as to how to implement this. Preferably, I can cache the results if they do not change.

Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement the [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (using the CakeDC search plugin)
2. Save the search params serialized and and hash them to get an unique key
3. If a new search is done you can identify by the hash if this search has been done before

However, the PRG alone allows you to go back in browser history already.

Instead of caching the results you should think about using a dedicated search index like Elastic Search or Sphinx or Lucene.

Comment: Which one would you recommend? Elastic Search, Sphinx or Lucene? I have used none of the above. The server is sitting within an intranet and is a Ubuntu. Running on Nginx and MySQL

Comment: I would use Elastic Search, it has a RESTful API to talk to it. Check the Elastica php library for it. There is an open source plugin for CakePHP as well but we didn't use that one because it was to limited for our use case. So we're using Elastica and built a plugin around that lib.

Comment: Can paste the link to the Elastica plugin? I found one, but it looks like it was discontinued.